# OpenCart seo friendly url issue

Tags: php, opencart

I got problem and now idea how to fix it. When I activate seo friendly url in OC (ver. 1.5.6.4 also using free "Marcus Design" theme from OC website) I getting fatal error:

> "Call to a member function getBanner() on a non-object"...

Code where error is:

```
$results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($this->data['marcusdesign_custom_banner_block1']);
```

Maybe annyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show the code where model_design_banner is initialized, because it seems from the error that initialization is missing or has failed.

Comment: The answers are not meant to add information like this. It is best, if you click on "edit" on your original post and add the information there. The "edit" button is below the tags. I would do this for you, but the code you provided is not the one I was asking for. Initialization means the creation of an object. `getBanner()` is called on `model_design_banner` and the error says that `model_design_banner` is a non-object. So this must mean it was never created. If you still don't know which code to provide, you need someone with programming knowledge to help you post yor question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it here (I am not a programmer so its hard to understand for me):

```
$results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($this->data['marcusdesign_custom_banner_block1']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if (file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
                $this->data['customBanner1'][] = array(
                    'title' => $result['title'],
                    'link'  => $result['link'],
                    'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], '248', '215')
                );
            }
        }
```